# Google BigQuery always divides column by comma

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to upload a .csv file in `BigQuery` with tab delimiter and even if I choose "tab" as custom delimiter in the settings it will still divide by comma. I can't figure out what is the problem. Is it because of my tuple format?
This is my data format:

```
time    zone_1  zone_2  zone_3

(18, 1, 1, 9)   (18, 360, 0.22) (193, 2702, 0.57)   (183, 7686, 0.14)

(18, 1, 1, 10)  (140, 5320, 0.51)   (138, 8280, 0.45)   (165, 6435, 0.23)

(18, 1, 1, 11)  (32, 448, 0.46)  (75, 1275, 0.57)   (90, 2610, 0.97)

(18, 1, 1, 12)  (117, 5382, 0.88)   (72, 2376, 0.72)    (119, 5593, 0.09)
```

and this is what I obtain after I upload

[image: big query columns]

Comment: I'm not 100% but this can be caused by autodetect schema. You can set delimiter only if you provide schema manually.

Comment: and if I use manual schema how should I proceed? I tried to add the 4 fields as in the first row but they are all empty after I save

Comment: are you using python?

Comment: @AlienDeg for now I just used the website but the next step is to use python to manipulate the data

Comment: Can you host a sample of your file somewhere? In your pasted lines I see spaces, not tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found JSON format like this to provide the right solution for you

```
{"time":"(18, 1, 1, 9)","zone_1":"(18, 1, 1, 9)","zone_2":"(193, 2702, 0.57)","zone_3":"(183, 7686, 0.14)"}
{"time":"(18, 1, 1, 9)","zone_1":"(18, 1, 1, 9)","zone_2":"(193, 2702, 0.57)","zone_3":"(183, 7686, 0.14)"}
```

This is the result in bigquery after the upload (Note: I pre-define the columns before the upload and didn't use the Automatically detect option)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to guarantee that your data is separate by TAB delimiter, some text editors replace by other type of SPACEs; that can cause Bigquery doesn't find the TAB, I prefer using vi or vim from linux to ensure this.

Then, you can start the process for [importing a CSV file into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table). When following steps, consider that you have to provide manually the column names to be able to select the TAB as the delimiter.

Here is the result I got:

[image]

With this configuration :

[image]

Comment: Yes, eventually I made it work. It also worked using commas by using this format: date,zone_1,zone_2,zone_3
2018-01-01 09:00,"[23, 1012, 0.8]","[71, 3124, 0.28]","[9, 396, 0.49]"